# Using the oxford comma to separate two entities of which one has an article

Tags: ambiguity, parallelism, oxford-comma

Considering that I do not want to switch the positions of the italicized nouns in this sentence:
"Taken as examples are the *Limboagan effect*, and *hysteria*."
Will it be correct to use the oxford comma to isolate the noun with the definite article to the other noun with zero article?

Comment: If you have a list of two things, it's not an Oxford comma.

Comment: Wrong site, but the comma does help give you what you want.

Comment: A comma before _and_ in 'Look at Jack and Jill'  would be rare and only used to show a pause for deliberation. With longer first members, a comma is permissible to aid parsing. '[T]he Limboagan effect' is probably borderline, but a comma here doesn't seem unreasonable even though the register is formal. It's not obligatory, on the other hand. // As Peter says, '_Oxford_ commas' only become an option/issue when the list contains 3 or more members.

Comment: No comma. You can mix articled and zero-articled items in a list of two (as signaled by your use of the plural *examples are*). No one will read *and [the] hysteria*.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat: I think he's worried about people reading it "the Limboagan effect and the Limboagan hysteria."

Comment: @PeterShor: Still, one would hardly read *the Brussels sprouts and cheese* as *the Brussels sprouts and the Brussels cheese*.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat: On the other hand, if it was *the French wine and cheese ...*

Comment: @PeterShor: On the third hand: ? _Taken as examples are the French wine and cheese._ (hm)